# UITableView's reused cells not getting drawn

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have created a tableview with grouped style. I have added this table to the subview of UIScrollView. I have calculated the size of the table according to the number of rows it has. So there is no scrolling for the tableView. I will be able to see all the cells.

For the first time the table works properly and shows all the cells. But my Problem is whenever I navigate to next page and come back and reload that table it is only rendering and redrawing the cells which were allocated. The cells which are getting reused are not getting redrawn. The tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: is also not getting called for those cells.

I am suspecting that since the scrolling of the tableview is disabled the cellForRowAtIndexPath method for the reused cells are not getting called and hence they are not getting rendered.

I have created the tableView in the following way

```
 m_TravellerDetailTable = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake( 2.0f, 0, 315.0f, 370 ) style: UITableViewStyleGrouped ];
 float height = (tableViewCellHeight * [travellersArray count]);
 m_TravellerDetailTable.frame = CGRectMake(2, 0, 315, height);
 [m_TravellerDetailTable setBounces: NO];
 [m_TravellerDetailTable setScrollEnabled: NO];
 [m_BaseScrollView addSubview: m_TravellerDetailTable];
```

UITableViewDelegate Methods

```
 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
   {
       return [travellersArray count];
   }

 -(CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
   {
       return tableViewCellHeight;
   }

   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {  

     static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
     cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
     if (cell == nil) 
     {

            cell = [[TravellerDetailCustomCellView alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
     }


     TravellerDetailCustomCellView *customCell = (TravellerDetailCustomCellView *)cell;
     [customCell.textLabel setText:[travellerInfoFromDetailForm objectForKey:@"DOB"]];
  }
```

This snapshot shows the uitableview rendering all the cells

[image: UITableView with all Cells]

The Snapshot shows the uitableview rendering only upto "Adult 8" cell. After that the table is not rendering the remaining cells.

[image: UITableView without reuesed cells]

Comment: Just a side note. When all of your cells have the same height, then it is more performant to set the rowHeight property of the table view rather than implementing heightForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: Where is the return from `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` ?

Comment: You talk about cell reuse, but there is no reuse in the code you have shown.  I would recommend you post complete code for methods (maybe simplified from your real program) that show the problem.

Comment: Do you want a scrolling table view or are you scrolling a view that contains a non-scrolling table view? If you want a scrolling table view, don't put it in a scroll view. `UITableView` is a subclass of `UIScrollView` and it handles scrolling automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is rendering, but your frame is to small and the table view is cut off.

You should remove

```
[m_TravellerDetailTable setBounces: NO];
[m_TravellerDetailTable setScrollEnabled: NO];
```

Comment: The frame is not small. I have set the bounces and ScrollEnabled to No because i have calculated the frame to fit all the cells in it. I have assigned the frame at only one place in the code. So there i no way of resizing the tableView.

Comment: If you look closely at the bottom of the tableview you can see the first few pixel of another cell. your frame must be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

it's caused by UIScrollView.The UIScrollView cached the drawing of it's subviews. I advice you dont add UITableView to UIScrollView

Comment: What do u mean by UIScrollView cached the drawing of its subview??? can u elaborate on that.

Comment: Are you saying that UITableView is already a UIScrollView, so you shouldn't put it inside another one?  There are a lot of posts saying how to make this work; I have never heard anything about a caching problem.

Comment: @Bryan sure it can work but what behavior is the asker wanting? If he wants a scrolling table view he shouldn't put it in a scroll view--it handles scrolling by itself.

Comment: I was trying to help interpret what @blackmilk might have meant.  I agree if Jayshree wants _just_ a scrolling table then he doesn't need another scrollview.  If there are other elements to the UI then maybe he does.